# How to group heading level in XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have an HTML of the following process.

```
<p class="Ahead">Heading 1</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
<p class="Bhead">Heading 1.1</p>
<p class="txt">Nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam</p>
<p class="list">Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere</p>
<p class="Chead">Heading 1.1.1</p>
<p class="txt">Typi non habent claritatem insitam</p>
<p class="Bhead">Heading 1.2</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

The heading is going on up to 5 levels. Different attributes are inbetween the heading.

The output should be follow below.

```
<section>
  <section-title>Heading 1</section-title>
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
  <section>
   <section-title>Heading 1.1</section-title>
    <p class="txt">Nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam</p>
    <p class="list">Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere</P>
    <section>
      <section-title>Heading 1.1.1</section-title>
      <p class="txt">Typi non habent claritatem insitam</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <section-title>Heading 1.2</section-title>
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are stuck with??

Comment: What exactly determines the level?

Comment: How to group heading levels using section tag and also follow section tag hierarchy.

Comment: @Shanmugalakshmi Could you answer my question, please? You say there are up to 5 levels; I asked what determines the level. Are the values "Ahead", "Bhead", etc. **constants** that one can use to determine the level of the heading?

Comment: Exactly, The five values are Ahead, Bhead, Chead, Dhead & Ehead. I will apply section tag for each group. Section should follow the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet uses XSLT 2.0 and was adapted from Michael Kay's ***XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference.pdf***, page 341-342.

When the stylesheet below is applied to your input XML (I have added a root node named `root` to your example input XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class='Ahead']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='Ahead']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='Ahead']|p[@class='Bhead']|p[@class='Chead']" mode="group">
        <xsl:variable name="this_att" select="substring-before(@class, 'head')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="concat(translate($this_att, 'ABCDEFGH', 'BCDEFGHI'), 'head')"/>
        <xsl:element name="section">
            <section-title><xsl:apply-templates/></section-title>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[@class = $next]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[not(ends-with(@class, 'head'))]" mode="group">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <section-title>Heading 1</section-title>
   <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
   <section>
      <section-title>Heading 1.1</section-title>
      <p class="txt">Nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam</p>
      <p class="list">Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere</p>
      <section>
         <section-title>Heading 1.1.1</section-title>
         <p class="txt">Typi non habent claritatem insitam</p>
      </section>
   </section>
   <section>
      <section-title>Heading 1.2</section-title>
      <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Hats off to XSL logics, +1

Comment: Saxon9he.jar does not convert the file. Because same mode (mode="group") use in two templates. So what can we do?

Comment: I am using Saxon-HE 9.4.0.3 and I am getting the output with no warnings or whatsoever. I also tried using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.6 in http://xsltransform.net/bdxtq8 and have obtained the same results.